# QPainter declared inside a run function creates artifact

Tags: qt

I am rendering a QPixmap inside of a QThread.  the code to paint is inside a function.  If I declare the painter inside the drawChart function everything seems ok but if I declare the painter inside the run function the image is wrong in the sense that at the edge of a black and white area, the pixels at the interface are overlapped to give a grey.  Does anyone know why this is so? Could it be because of the nature of the run function itself?

```
//This is ok  
void RenderThread::run()  
{  
  QImage image(resultSize, QImage::Format_RGB32);  
  drawChart(&image);  
  emit renderedImage(image, scaleFactor);  
}

drawChart(&image)  
{  
  QPainter painter(image);
  painter.doStuff()(;  
  ...  
}  

//This gives a image that seems to have artifacts  
void RenderThread::run()  
{  
  QImage image(resultSize, QImage::Format_RGB32);  
  QPainter painter(image);  
  drawChart(painter);  
  emit renderedImage(image, scaleFactor);  
}  

drawChart(&painter)
{   
  painter.doStuff();    
  ...  
}
```

//bad
[image: Valid XHTML].
//good
[image: Valid XHTML].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield:

> One important thing to understand is
>   that the center of a pixel lies on
>   “half-pixel” coordinates. For example,
>   the top-left pixel covers the area
>   between points (0, 0) and (1, 1), and
>   its center is located at (0.5, 0.5).
>   If we ask QPainter to draw a pixel at,
>   say, (100, 100), it will approximate
>   the result by shifting the coordinate
>   by +0.5 in both directions, resulting
>   in the pixel centered at (100.5,
>   100.5) being drawn.
>
> This distinction may seem rather
>   academic at first, but it has
>   important consequences in practice.
>   First, the shifting by +0.5 only
>   occurs if antialiasing is disabled
>   (the default); if antialiasing is
>   enabled and we try to draw a pixel at
>   (100, 100) in black, QPainter will
>   actually color the four pixels (99.5,
>   99.5), (99.5, 100.5), (100.5, 99.5), and (100.5, 100.5) light gray, to give
>   the impression of a pixel lying
>   exactly at the meeting point of the
>   four pixels. If this effect is
>   undesirable, we can avoid it by
>   specifying half-pixel coordinates, for
>   example, (100.5, 100.5).